# Vue3 Components in a Separate File

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have an app that I am porting from Vue2 to Vue3. I am not using a bundler as Vue is just providing simple interactivity on a page. This is the simplified version in Vue2:

```js
// my-modal.js
var myModal = Vue.component('my-modal',
{
    template:
        `<div id="myModal">
        <button @click.prevent="open=true">Open Modal</button>

        <div v-if="open" class="my-modal">
            <p>Hello from the modal!</p>
            <button @click.prevent="open=false">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            open: false
        }
     }
})
```

In Vue 2 this Works;

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="outer">
        <h3>Modal Example - {{ message }}</h3>
        <div>
            <my-modal />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/js/my-modal.js"></script>

<script>
   const app = new Vue(
   {
       el: '#app',
       data() {
           return {
               message: 'Hello Vue!'
           }
       }
   });
</script>
```

For Vue3, per the documentation at: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp  I switched things over to what I expected would work:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="outer">
        <h3>Modal Example - {{ message }}</h3>
        <div>
            <my-modal />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/js/my-modal.js"></script>

<script>
   Vue.createApp({
      data()
      {
          return {
              message: 'Hello Vue!'
          }
      }
   }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

and in the my-modal.js file I changed the first few lines to use the Global Vue:

```js
 const { createApp } = Vue;
 const app = createApp({});

 app.component('my-modal', ...
```

The Vue instance works but the component is not found with the error message: "Failed to resolve component: my-modal". I tried adding a 'components' section to the Vue instance and a few other things with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance from `createApp()` is *unique*. That is, calling `createApp()` in `index.html` does not return the same instance from the previous call in `my-modal.js`.

One solution is to declare the global `app` instance *before* importing `my-modal.js`:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
window._app = Vue.createApp({⋯})
</script>

<script src="/js/my-modal.js"></script>

<script>
// finally mount
window._app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

```js
// js/my-modal.js
window._app.component('my-modal', {⋯})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-global-component-registration-static-html?file=index.html)